# Empty query string parameters with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

Is it possible to add "empty" query string parameters with ASP.NET MVC? I need to somehow generate the following url using `Html.ActionLink`:

/Home/Index?foo

However this `Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new {foo = ""})` will output

/Home/Index

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to use Url.Action() instead of Html.ActionLink.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Index") %>?foo">Index</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand your problem a little more, no I do not think there is a way to force the ActionLink() function to have an empty string valued query string parameter.

So the next question is... are there any semantic issues with converting a null value for `foo` to an empty string?

Comment: Yes, I want to handle null in a different way from empty string to avoid passing some dummy values such as space or anything else. I think the other response is the way to go.